# No such filter in ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to create the slideshow with below command.

Here is the command I have executed:

```
 ffmpeg
-loop 1 -t 1 -i /sdcard/input0.png 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i /sdcard/input1.png 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i /sdcard/input2.png 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i /sdcard/input3.png 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i /sdcard/input4.png 
-filter_complex 
"[0:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v0]; 
 [1:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v1]; 
 [2:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v2]; 
 [3:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v3]; 
 [4:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v4]; 
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" /sdcard/out.mp4
```

on execution of this command it gives error something like:

```
 onFailure: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mjpeg @ 0x4362af10] Changing bps to 8
Input #0, image2, from '/sdcard/img0001.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2410 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 259x194 [SAR 1:1 DAR 259:194], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mjpeg @ 0x436300a0] Changing bps to 8
Input #1, image2, from '/sdcard/img0002.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2053 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 290x174 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mjpeg @ 0x436383a0] Changing bps to 8
Input #2, image2, from '/sdcard/img0003.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3791 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 300x168 [SAR 1:1 DAR 25:14], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mjpeg @ 0x43648f50] Changing bps to 8
Input #3, image2, from '/sdcard/img0004.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1796 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 259x194 [SAR 1:1 DAR 259:194], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mjpeg @ 0x437b4070] Changing bps to 8
Input #4, image2, from '/sdcard/img0005.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1083 kb/s
    Stream #4:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 212x160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 53:40], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x4393c960] No such filter: '"'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

and i used this demo https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: You need to show the full command and the complete console output so we can see what is actually going on.

Comment: Looks like the usual Android quotation shenanigans. Try without any quotes or search this site for what the many other users did. Also, each of your image inputs have a different width and height. This will likely result in stretched/squished output frames.

Comment: i referred this links:
http://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg/834035#834035

http://superuser.com/questions/1078920/how-to-pass-arguments-to-blend-filter-ffmpeg/1079163

http://superuser.com/questions/1002562/convert-multiple-images-to-a-gif-with-cross-dissolve?lq=1

Comment: try , instead of ; in android command array and remove ' ' space after each ;

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Node.JS, but it should work anywhere.

```
var exec = require('child_process');
const execFFMpeg = function() {
    console.log('... ffmpeg executing');
    const process = exec.execFile(
        'ffmpeg',
        [
            "-loop", "1", "-t", "2", "-i", "./images/0036d185-9d8c-4636-87b4-d3633c072ca1_original_Britain-Weather-38.jpg",
            "-loop", "1", "-t", "2", "-i", "./images/0024882d-4cb9-4722-a0a2-7efaf7ca67eb_original_Pelicans_Bucks_Basketball_59.jpg",
            "-loop", "1", "-t", "2", "-i", "./images/005a7a78-1f16-441a-b045-13f5d8a6fa1c_original_Houston_Rodeo_67.jpg",
            "-loop", "1", "-t", "2", "-i", "./images/00631475-78db-424c-bea1-8bc190300e51_original_Britain_Northern_Lights_8.jpg",
            "-loop", "1", "-t", "2", "-i", "./images/00bab729-43eb-4cd9-b2c8-e23867e3dbc6_original_Golf_Course_Plane_Crash_79.jpg",
            "-filter_complex",
            "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v];[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v];[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v];[4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b4v];[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v][4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]",
            "-map", "[v]", "1ddba2f2-1e8e-11e7-b451-069f7b36a73b_original_generated-showcase-video.mp4"
        ],
        {
            cwd: './image-rendition'
        },
        function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('... ffmpeg is compeled:');
        }
    );

    process.stdout.on('data', console.log);
    process.stderr.on('data', console.error);
};
execFFMpeg();
```

Please remove any spaces between filter_complex rules.

Thanks.